# how to remove the repeated value in an array and in between arrays using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I need to find the repeated value and give an alert using jQuery. Below is the example arrays and my requirement. Please help.

```
            a1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,4}
            a2= {9,8,7},
            a3= {a,b,c,d,e,7}
```

In the above arrays I need to get the value 4 and give alert because it is repeating in array "a1" and I need to get the value 7 because it is repeating in the arrays 'a2' and 'a3'.
The first issue I fixed like as follows. Ineed to to fix the second one.

```
        for (var $i = 0; $i<= $last; $i++)
        {
        var hours = [];
        var minutes = [];
        var activeTime = [];    
        $.each($('.hour'+$i),function() {
       hours.push($(this).val());    
         });
       $.each($('.hour'+$i).next('select'),function(){
        minutes.push($(this).val());
       });
       for ( var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++ ) {
          activeTime.push(hours[ i ]+":"+minutes[ i ]+":"+"00");
         }
         for ( var i = 0; i <= hours.length; i++ ) {
          if ( hours[ i ] === "" )
           {
          $("#timeValidate"+$i).css("display", "block");
           return false;
           }
            else
             {
            $("#timeValidate"+$i).css("display", "none");
            }
            }
          for(var i=0; i< activeTime.length; i++)
          {
           for(var j = 0; j< activeTime.length; j++)
           {
          if( i != j)
             {
           if(activeTime[j] == activeTime[i])
              {
            $("#timeValidate"+$i).text("");
            $("#timeValidate"+$i).text("active time"+activeTime[j]+" is repeating");
             $("#timeValidate"+$i).css("display", "block");
            return false;
            }
            }
             }
            }
           }
```

Comment: Those don't look like arrays, in fact that's invalid syntax.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: it is just an example not exact code

Comment: the correct format is a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,4], '[]' not '{}'

Comment: Hint: `concat` your arrays before checking for duplicates. That way you don't have to care about whether or not the duplicates are in different source arrays.

Comment: This is nothing pure JS can't solve. Consider removing the JQ tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDuplicatesFromArrays() {
    var allItems = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
    var duplicates = [];
    var hash = {};

    allItems.forEach(function(x) {
        if(hash.hasOwnProperty(x)) duplicates.push(x);
        hash[x] = 1;
    });

    return duplicates;
}
```

The above function accepts any number of arrays, and yields the duplicates:

```
getDuplicatesFromArrays(a1,a2,a3) // [4, 7]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL64c/)

It works as sort of an inverse hash sieve; adding to duplicates only if the item was already in the hash.

Comment: How to call  the function with 'n' number of array using a loop

Comment: @Mansoor: the function accepts any number of arrays `getDuplicatesFromArrays(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)` would be fine, if those are all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var original = [].concat(a,b,c),
    dupes = [];
for (var c = 0; c < original.length; c++) {
    if (original.filter(function(v) {
        return v == original[c];
    }).length > 1) {
        dupes.push(original[c]);
    }
}
alert($.grep(dupes, function(v, k){return $.inArray(v , dupes) === k;}));
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q2c42/

Comment: There will be n times of array then how we will try this

Comment: @Mansoor Updated and provided an example. Also alerts the dupes only once.

Comment: This demo yields an empty array for me.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Gives me `[4,7]`, although the previous version had this problem. Try refreshing the page and trying the demo ([this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEYcn/1/))

Comment: @Asad: yes, it still yields `[]` when I run it in Chrome. Perhaps a browser difference; jQuery does not guarantee that `$.unique` will work this way, if it does in some browsers, that is accidental. From the docs: *[Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)*

Comment: @Asad: yes, your demo isn't updated so I used the code in your answer. It works, if I replace `arr` with `original` and `dupes`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api), it has advanced functions for arrays (and others). For example, you can use a combination of unique() and subtract() to get an array that contains only the elements that are repeated. Then you can parse it and alert for each one.